# iOS Libavcodec - Trim and convert a video

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, video-processing, libavcodec

In my iOS project, I am trying to take an .mp4 video file, cut out a small clip in the middle of the file, and convert the output to .mov file. I am using libavcodec to do this.

I built the FFmpeg libraries for iOS using [this script](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) and added to my project.

The code I am using to trim and convert the video file is [this](https://bitbucket.org/AnujAroshA/privaterepo/src/d194156ae09f29f7ec4fc0ebc66f4ad48d8a0ad2/ViewController.m?at=master).

The issues with final output of the file are:

1. When I copy the output from the iPhone to my mac, the video meta data for duration and video dimensions are blank. If I do the same for the original, I get the video length and dimensions correctly. I must not be creating the video meta data on the new video correctly.
2. The frame rate on the outputted video appears to be wrong. I expect to see e.g. 250 frames over 10 seconds (25fps), but instead I see 250 frames over 4 seconds, then only the last frame for the remaining 6 seconds.
3. The code should seek to 100s in the video before starting trimming. Instead, the code appears to crop the video starting at the beginning.

Comment: Anuj any luck with this? Am also trying to do the same.

Comment: @objectivecdeveloper I gave up using FFmpeg and used AVFoundation framework.

Comment: :( I need to trim server video, which is not possible locally.